# unable to get values from user-defined functions

Tags: c++, function

I'm trying to retrieve data from a user-define function unfortunately, i'm not able to do so.

For instance, i have two user-define function that is

> getPosition : In order to know the position on a graph based on a user input
>
> printPosition : In order to display information based on the position of the graph

So for example for my `getPosition`, i did a simple if else statement

```
char getPosition (float x, float y){

char position;

if (x > 0 && y > 0)

    position = 1;

else if (x < 0 && y > 0)

    position = 2;

 ......
 
return position;
```

Next, i try to `printPosition` using a switch case

```
    switch(position)
{

    case '1' : cout << "==> (" << x << ", " << y << ") is above X-axis" << endl;
               cout << "==> It is at first quadrant" << endl;
               break;
               
    case '2' : cout << "==> (" << x << ", " << y << ") is above X-axis" << endl;
               cout << "==> It is at second quadrant" << endl;
               break;

   .......

}
```

So after having two user-define function, i attempted to call for the values in `getPosition` to print out the data from `printPosition`

```
printPosition(x, y, getPosition(x,y));
```

However, it does not produce any output. Why is this so.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: I would be happy to debug if it produces any error, unfortunately, I managed to compile them thus, making it very hard for me to figure what is the issue .

Comment: That is not debugging.  debugging is running the program and stepping through the code line by line to see how it works and what is going on.  It is what you do after it compiles without errors but still does not work.  If you click on the link from my previous comment it will show you how you can debug your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either change:

```
position = 1;
position = 2;
...
```

To:

```
position = '1';
position = '2';
...
```

---

Or change:

```
case '1':
case '2':
...
```

To:

```
case 1:
case 2:
...
```

Comment: ... because `'1'` is a char and its corresponding ASCII (or utf8) code is 49, so `'1' != 1`...

Comment: Why not have the function return int?

Comment: @DanKorn It doesn't really matters. It could return an enum too, as long as it matches the `case`s.

Answer (score 0):

Having

```
position = '1';
position = '2';
```

You should also always have a default statement in your switch statement as this helps you understand that none of the case statements were executed, a simple way of debugging.

Can implement like this:

```
switch(position)
{
case '1':
//whatever
break;
case '2':
//whatever
break;
default:
//Can have a message like:
cout << "The value was not in any of the case statements" << endl;
//No break needed for default statements
}
```